# Py4JJavaError java.sql.SQLException: Method not supported." Error while trying to fetch hive tables via pyspark using connection string

Tags: python, pyspark, hive, database-connection, data-extraction

I'm trying to extract hive tables from a server using connection details via pyspark.

Here is the code :

```
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext 
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext 

database = "some_db_name"
table = "some_table_name"
user = "user"
password  = "pwd"

#read table data into a spark dataframe
jdbcDF = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", f"jdbc:hive2://dbslp_server:10159/{database};") \
    .option("dbtable", table) \
    .option("user", user) \
    .option("password", password) \
    .option("driver", "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver") \
    .load()
```

I'm basically trying to connect to a server which has hive tables in it , while authenticating my credentials to that server with hive driver. However i get the following error:

> ---
>
> Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>        10     .option("user", user) \
>        11     .option("password", password) \
>   ---> 12     .option("driver", "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver") \
>        13     .load()
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in
>   load(self, path, format, schema, **options)
>       170             return self._df(self._jreader.load(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
>       171         else:
>   --> 172             return self._df(self._jreader.load())
>       173 
>       174     @since(1.4)
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in
>   **call**(self, *args)    1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)    1256         return_value
>   = get_return_value(
>   -> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)    1258     1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py in
>   deco(*a, **kw)
>        61     def deco(*a, **kw):
>        62         try:
>   ---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
>        64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
>        65             s = e.java_exception.toString()
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py in
>   get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
>       326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
>       327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
>   --> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
>       329             else:
>       330                 raise Py4JError(
>
> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o623.load. :
>   java.sql.SQLException: Method not supported   at
>   org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.setQueryTimeout(HiveStatement.java:739)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:60)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation$.getSchema(JDBCRelation.scala:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:35)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:318)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor12.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I understand that it is a driver related error, tried to change other hive related drivers, but all in vain, as the same error still persists.Do I have to download any driver. explicitly or link it in any other way?

Can anybody please throw some light on this issue and let me know how I can solve this?
Or is there any other way I can achieve  this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Download Hive JDB jar https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hive/hive-jdbc/3.1.2/hive-jdbc-3.1.2.jar
2. Add the jar to Spark 's /jar directory.
3. Restart your server
4. Run your PySpark Job

Make sure you have below jars with the right version in your Spark folder

- ibthrift-0.9.0.jar
- httpclient-4.2.5.jar
- httpcore-4.2.5.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
- hive-common.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
- hive-metastore.jar
- hive-service.jar
- hadoop-common.jar
- hive-jdbc.jar
- guava-11.0.2.jar

Comment: Thank you for quick response.However I am getting further error that says:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hive/service/rpc/thrift/TCLIService$Iface
 at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:107)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:63)`

Can you also please let me know how to resolve this or why I am getting this error?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: please update the question with whole new error stack trace. This line is does not gives complete picture of the error @Mrinalinimadhusudan

Comment: here you go:
Attaching the error message in multiple parts as there is char limit in comments

```Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o166.load.
: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: HIVE_CLI_SERVICE_PROTOCOL_V10
 at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:205)
 at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:107)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:63) ```

Comment: ```at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:54)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:56)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation$.getSchema(JDBCRelation.scala:210)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:35)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:318)
```

Comment: ```at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)```

Comment: ```at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
 at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
 at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
 at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
 at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
 at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```
Thanks in Advance